# 301 .htaccess from Wordpress root to page

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to get Apache to redirect **subdomain.example.com** to **subdomain.example.com/home**

I got the the redirect to work with this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.example.com/home$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ home [L]
```

The problem is that if I go to edit a post, the rewrite rules conflict, and this is returned.

```
http://subdomain.example.com/homewp-admin/post.php?post=51&action=edit
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your rules before WP rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!home/).*)$ /home/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^$ home [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Didn't work. Results in a redirect loop of **example.com/homehomehomehome[etc]**

Comment: I made another update, missed a `slash` earlier. Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching.